# Netbeans and Xampp

Tags: php, netbeans, ubuntu, xampp, lamp

I installed netbeans with php plugin.I also installed XAMP.My problem is how to configure /opt/lampp/htdocs/ to my netbeans application so that I can debug and run that from the application.Problem is when I try to make a project inside from netbeans it does not allow me to create files on that localhost.I guess netbeans doesn't have write access to the file system. What to do?any help??

Comment: Guessing is very bad for debugging. Can you say something specific you know by fact why something is not working? Which tutorial did you follow so far to do your setup?

Comment: Do you see a page when you request http://localhost/ ? Running the site from your htdocs in netbeans should just be a set in the project settings.

Comment: You are making many different questions. NetBeans is just an IDE. You still need a web server, a PHP interpreter, a debug client... And `localhost` doesn't really mean anything: it's just a network alias for your own computer.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario " Guys XAMPP will do the PHP part,its a combination of PHP,MYSQL,FTP and so on, thats why i said i install XAMPP,the problem wil be understand if you use the NetBEANS, because, in Netbeans for PHP we can create an app with localhost feature in it, but on linux, my dir of htdocs is in opt/lampp/htdocs/ ,as of the security problem i cant create a file in that folder through netbeans,and i asked how we can rectify that?, i do the same thing in windows, but now in linux, it not getting done as opt/lampp/htdocs is protected

Comment: @hakre : what specific details you need?

Comment: @JamesGoodwin : localhost is working, ftp is working, my localhost dir is opt/lampp/htdocs and in netbeans i cant create a file or save file of some security, which i dont gave and automatically for that folder

Answer (score 4):

1. Open your UNIX Terminal
2. Run the `sudo chmod 777 /opt/lampp/htdocs` command and give `sudo` your password when prompted

Your `htdocs` directory should now be rewritable.

Answer (score 3):

You could set up a virtual host to point to your project directory which needs to reside in a directory that is writable.  Here's a link to a tutorial for setting up a virtual host using XAMP:

[Setting Up Virtual Hosts for XAMPP](http://sawmac.com/xampp/virtualhosts/)